# python read zipfile into numpy-array efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, python-zipfile

I want to read a zipfile into memory and extract its content into a numpy array (as numpy-datatypes). This needs to happen in an extremely efficient/fast manner, since the files are rather big and there are many of them. Unfortunately looking at similiar questions didn't help me, because I couldn't find a way to convert the data into numpy-datatypes at the time of reading. Also the speed turned out to be a big problem.

For example: The zipfile "log_ks818.zip" contains "log_file.csv", which contains the needed data in the following format (yyyymmdd hhnnsszzz,float,float,zero):

```
20161001 190000100,1.000500,1.000800,0
20161001 190001000,1.001000,1.002000,0
20161001 190002500,1.001500,1.001200,0
...
```

The fastest that I managed to do so far (using pandas):

```
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile("log_ks818.zip", 'r')
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(zfile.read("log_file.csv")), header=None, usecols=[0, 1, 2], delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8')
print(df.head())
```

However this takes around 6 seconds for ~2,000,000 lines in the file (~80MB if unpacked), which is too slow (plus it's not a numpy object). When I compared the read-in speed of different numpy/pandas-methods, using the extracted file on the hard drive to test, np.fromfile performed the best with 0.08 seconds to simply get it into memory. It would be nice if it was possible to stay in this magnitude when reading the data from the zip-file.

Comment: Are you clearing your cache after the first test? Because if not, your subsequent tests aren't really measuring reading the file from disk.

Comment: I think so. If I start the script which executes nothing but the np.fromfile/zfile-test from scratch, I get 0.08s and 6s, every single time. I'm not sure where caching could even occur in this.

Comment: For loading a csv file, the `pandas` reader is supposedly these fastest.  Numpy loaders read the file line by line and build a list of lists from that.  I don't think the zip part makes a difference.

Comment: The filesystem caches, that's where. Agreed with @hpaulj that the pandas csv reader is one of the fastest ways to ingest something csv-like into python.

Comment: @P.Zeek, you could zcat the vial in the shell via subprocess and pipe that stream to pandas, might be faster. consider storing your files from bandas to bcolz --> way better

Comment: @PlagTag One of my first attempts was using 'unzip' in the shell and having numpy read from that stream. This took way longer than the code I posted above, so I abandoned that approach, believing the pipe to be the bottleneck. If there is a better way to do this, it would be great if you would post an answer and show me an example (that would also yield the np.dtypes I need).

Comment: @hpaulj & pvg why doesn't the zip part make a difference? And I don't know of a way to get the np.dtypes I need using pandas. An example that works with the data-snippet above would be nice.

Comment: @hpaulj I also do not understand why pandas reader is considered the fastest, when in fact it is 35 times slower then numpy.fromfile (according to the benchmarking done here https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7463/fastest-python-library-to-read-a-csv-file). I assume pd.read_csv and pandas.io.parsers.read_csv (which allegedly beats everybody else) are the same, since pandas __init__ does not contain the 'io'-reference.

Comment: If you can use the array that `fromfile` gives you, use it.  It reads the whole file as a flat sequence of numbers.  Most `csv` readers want the features that `pandas` handles, like headers, mixed column types, missing data etc.

Comment: If I read the 2014 benchmarks correctly, `fromfile` is being used in its binary mode, reading a file created with `tofile`.  `fromfile` in text mode might be much slower. Test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a problem about read speed from disk. Even though you are using HDD, reading 80MB into memory can be done in one second.

Take my experience as an example, the cost of time is determined by the process of uncompressing. If you just work with extracted data, it won't cost you a lot I believe.

Comment: The extracted file (80MB) needs 30 times more space than the zip file (2.6MB), because the content of the csv-file is redundant at times and can therefore easily be compressed. That is why I am trying to extract only the required files on demand and in memory only.